# Initializing weights of each module in a Sequential Module in LibTorch

Tags: pytorch, libtorch

I am trying to port some code from PyTorch to LibTorch.

Supposing in a struct inheriting from torch::nn::Module I have a registered sequential module like

```
branch1 = register_module("branch1", torch::nn::Sequential(torch::nn::Conv2d(torch::nn::Conv2dOptions(in_channels, branch_channels, kernel_size).padding(0)),
                torch::nn::BatchNorm2d(torch::nn::BatchNorm2dOptions(branch_channels)), 
                torch::nn::ReLU());
```

I am interested in applying a weight initialization function to each component separately (ideally with a different initialization algorithm per module type), say a function that takes in a torch::nn::Module or a pointer to a torch::nn::Module, what is the simplest way to achieve this?

Edit: My current attempt.

```
#include <torch/torch.h>

using namespace std;


void init_conv(torch::nn::Conv2d& conv) {
    torch::NoGradGuard noGrad;
    torch::nn::init::kaiming_normal_(conv->weight, 0.0, torch::kFanOut, torch::kReLU);
    torch::nn::init::constant_(conv->bias, 0);
}

void init_bn_2d(torch::nn::BatchNorm2d& bn_2d) {
    torch::NoGradGuard noGrad;
    torch::nn::init::constant_(bn_2d->weight, 1);
    torch::nn::init::constant_(bn_2d->bias, 0);
}

void initialize_sequential(torch::nn::Sequential& seq) {
torch::NoGradGuard noGrad;
vector<shared_ptr<torch::nn::Module>> mods = seq->modules();
for (auto mod = std::begin(mods); mod != end(mods); ++mod) {
    shared_ptr<torch::nn::Module> m = *mod;
    torch::nn::Module* m_ = m.get();
    if (typeid(*m_) == typeid(torch::nn::Conv2dImpl*)) {
        torch::nn::Conv2d* c = dynamic_cast<torch::nn::Conv2d*>(m_);
        init_conv(*c);
    }
    if (typeid(*m_) == typeid(torch::nn::BatchNorm2dImpl*)) {
        torch::nn::BatchNorm2d* bn = dynamic_cast<torch::nn::BatchNorm2d*>(m_);
        init_bn_2d(*bn);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried ? What is blocking you ? I imagine you could iterate over the children of the module and dynamic_cast them to the proper type to call for the right init method

Comment: @trialNerror updated with my first attempt, and final solution which suits my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can use the apply() function on the sequential object like this:

```
    #include <torch/torch.h>
    void sequential_init_weights(torch::nn::Module& m){
           if ((typeid(m) == typeid(torch::nn::Conv2dImpl))) {
                auto p = m.named_parameters(false);
                auto w = p.find("weight");
                auto b = p.find("bias");
        
                if (w != nullptr) torch::nn::init::kaiming_normal_(*w, 0.0, 
                                  torch::kFanOut, torch::kReLU);
                if (b != nullptr) torch::nn::init::constant_(*b, 0.0);
            }
            if ((typeid(m) == typeid(torch::nn::BatchNorm2dImpl))) {
                auto p = m.named_parameters(false);
                auto w = p.find("weight");
                auto b = p.find("bias");
        
                if (w != nullptr) torch::nn::init::constant_(*w, 1.0);
                if (b != nullptr) torch::nn::init::constant_(*b, 0.0);
            }
        }  
    
    struct example_mod : torch::nn::Module {
        example_mod(int64_t in_channels, int64_t out_channels) {
            m = register_module("m", torch::nn::Sequential(torch::nn::Conv2d(torch::nn::Conv2dOptions(in_channels, out_channels, 1)), 
                        torch::nn::BatchNorm2d(torch::nn::BatchNorm2dOptions(out_channels), 
             torch::nn::ReLU()));
            m->apply(sequential_init_weights);
        }
        torch::nn::Sequential m = nullptr;
    };
```

Basically just write a function that parses the modules by typeid then used the named parameters to get what you need and pass those to an init function, seems to work pretty well.

Comment: That's a nice solution ! You can mark this answer as accepted now. Cheers